# Create an object that holds objects?

Tags: java, parent-child

I am attempting to create an inventory tracking system. I have a class (in Java) called "InventoryItem" with the properties of name and quantity.

This works fine for simple objects, but what if my inventory item contains other inventory items, for example, a server with RAM?

Should I be creating my own datatype, or is there a better way to do this (linked listed maybe)? should my class extend whatever that datatype is or should I not bother creating my own class?

My class so far:

```
public class InventoryItem {
    private String name;
    private int quantity;
    private InventoryItem childInventoryItem;

    // CONSTRUCTORS
    public InventoryItem() {
    }

    public InventoryItem(int quantity, String name) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.name = name;
    }

    //GETTERS
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    //SETTERS

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Just use a `List` for all children.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by it could have other inventoryitems. Of course it could. You can just put all of the `InventoryItem`s into a LinkedList<InventoryItem> to use them elsewhere in your code. And then you just set the name to "Server with RAM" for one of the InventoryItems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tree is usually what is involved in any parent-child relationship. If you aren't doing anything complicated, you can simply maintain an internal list that is basically `List<InventoryItem>` which contains any child items.

So all you would add to your class is something like this:

```
public class InventoryItem {

    ...
    private List<InventoryItem> composingItems = new ArrayList<>(); //if still using Java 6 this must be new ArrayList<InventoryItem>();

    ...

    public void addComposingItem(InventoryItem composingItem) {
        composingItems.add(composingItems);
    }

    public List<InventoryItem> getComposingItems() {
        //Enforce immutability so no one can mess with the collection. However
        //this doesn't guarantee immutability for the objects inside the list;
        //you will have to enforce that yourself.
        return Collections.umodifiableList(composingItems);
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, I have seen that before. Would it be better to have a List as a part of my class, or should my class extend list? or is that up to my implementation?

Comment: @Jeff It should be part of your class. You shouldn't extend `List<T>`! Always think hard about whether inheritance is necessary; prefer composition over it.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you can do this.  I think the easiest way would be to create an array list.

```
ArrayList<InventoryItem> childInventory = new ArrayList<InventoryItem>();
```

Then create a setter that adds inventory items to this array

```
public void addChildItem(InventoryItem child)
    childInventory.add(child);
```

This way you would have a list of all of the child items within the item.  You could also make a method to return a list of all of the child items in either an array or an ArrayList.

```
public ArrayList<InventoryItem> getChildItems()
    return childInventory;
```